# Block IP range on asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using this code to block ip addresses on iis.

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
    <add ipAddress="1.1.1.1" allowed="true" />
    <add ipAddress="2.2.2.2" allowed="true" />
</ipSecurity>
```

Now, is it possible to block an iprange? thanks in advance

Comment: Yes.  First hit on a google search for "asp.net web.config ipsecurity tag":  http://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-ip-address-restriction.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
```